# best way to collapse a sparsely populated matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sparsely populated matrix that's the result of a series of left joins. I'd like to collapse it down to a single row (see below). The only solution I've seen to this is a GROUP BY on the PK and a MAX() on ColA, ColB etc. Performance is a huge issue here, so I'd like to know if anyone has a better solution. The columns ColA, ColB etc are rows that have been pivoted to columns. My understanding is that I can't use a PIVOT because the columns are coming from rows (1 to n) and could change at any given time.

Join that produces the SPM (no, my tables/cols aren't really named that):

```
    SELECT    
   mainTable.custNbr  
   , mainTable.custPartNbr             
    , [lkup colA].usr_def_attr as [colA]
    , [lkup colB].usr_def_attr as [colB]
    , [lkup colC].usr_def_attr as [colC]
    , [lkup colD].usr_def_attr as [colD]
    , [lkup colE].usr_def_attr as [colE]
  FROM db2.dbo.table2 as mainTable           
    LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.lookup as [colA]
        ON mainTable.lookupValue = [colA].lkup_id     
        and mainTable.cmply_typ_lkup_id = 166697 
    LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.lookup as [lkup colB]
        ON mainTable.lookupValue = [lkup colB].lkup_id    
        and mainTable.cmply_typ_lkup_id = 166700 
    LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.lookup as [lkup colC]
        ON mainTable.lookupValue = [lkup colC].lkup_id    
        and mainTable.cmply_typ_lkup_id = 166699 
    LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.lookup as [lkup colD]
        ON mainTable.lookupValue = [lkup colD].lkup_id    
        and mainTable.cmply_typ_lkup_id = 166696 
    LEFT JOIN db1.dbo.lookup as [lkup colE]
        ON mainTable.lookupValue = [lkup colE].lkup_id    
        and mainTable.cmply_typ_lkup_id = 166698
```

Result:

```
PKCol   ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE
204045  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    23
204045  NULL    NULL    NULL    35  NULL
204045  NULL    NULL    35      NULL    NULL
204045  NULL    23  NULL    NULL    NULL
204045  23  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Desired result:

```
PKCol   ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE
20405   23  23  35      35  23
```

Comment: Let me clarify just one thing: "Start point" is already a table, not just a result set from your current query? (i.e., we cannot affect how "Start point" is generated?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote this as a PIVOT and saw a performance increase of about 30%. It wasn't easy to do, had to read [**this post**](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx) very carefully. PIVOTs are weird.

Answer (score 3):

The GROUPY BY + MAX solution isn't a bad one. Since it's going to be scanning over the same number of records whether or not you're doing aggregates.

I'd be curious to know what the time difference with and without grouping is.

Comment: +1. I misunderstood the question at first, but now that I got it figured out, I believe it's hard to beat this solution (unless, perhaps, if you write a procedure to do it).

Answer (score -2):

Sparse matricies are common in linear algebra, numerical methods, and modeling of physics problems.  If a matrix is diagonal, it's easy to represent it using a single vector.  A bandwidth approach might require storing both row and column indicies for a non-zero element.

Googling for "sparse matrix storage" brought back lots of hits, including [this](http://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~gaggle/EVENTS/2006/BRENT60/presentations/Shahadat%20Hossain%20-%20On%20efficient%20data%20structures%20for%20sparse%20matrix%20storage.pdf).  Maybe it can stimulate some ideas.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I think if people are gonna downvote they should *have a better answer*!